# Change Mailgun to SMTP at Runtime in Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, mailgun

Laravel version 5.2.22
I have tried these to change the mailgun to smtp at runtime:

```
config(['MAIL_DRIVER' => 'SMTP']); //not work.
Config::set('MAIL_DRIVER', 'SMTP'); //not work.
```

Comment: You're asking a question and answering it in less than a minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I get these work:

```
Config::set('mail.driver', 'SMTP'); //works.
config(['mail.driver'=>'smtp']); //works.
```

I don't really know why have to change the MAIL_DRIVER to mail.driver.

```
Config::get('mail.driver'); //you can use this to check the config.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer Alex gave himself is the solution, it should be:

```
Config::set('mail.driver', 'SMTP');
```

The following does not work, as usually the env variable defining the mail driver is called MAIL_DRIVER, not the config variable. (See `config/mail.php` for the assignment of `config('mail.driver')`).

```
Config::set('MAIL_DRIVER', 'SMTP'); //config var MAIL_DRIVER does not exist yet / is not used.
```